# Workbench : UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379

Tags: workbench

workbench stopped working suddenly with the above error, Could anyone please let me know how the developer and admin world overcame this problem.
Any workarounds or recommendations for free apps of similar capability would be really helpful, Thanks